# Coding an awk command inside a perl script

Tags: perl, awk

I have two types of tab separated input files, the first is a matrix which has names listed vertically in the first column, and numerical values in subsequent columns. The second type of input contains a single column with a subset of the same names listed in the first column of the first file type.

EX: input1

```
Gary 1 2 3
Yolanda 3 4 5
Biff 5 6 7
Hubert 8 9 10
```

EX: input2

```
Gary
Biff
```

While there are several different variations on input2, there is only a single input1. I have a perl script with an embedded awk command which is supposed to match names from input2 to input1 and print an output file which contains the names from input2 and the respective values from input1.

EX: outputfile

```
Gary 1 2 3
Biff 5 6 7
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir1 = '../FeatureSelection/Chunks/ArffPreprocessing';
my $dir2 = '../DataFiles';

opendir(DIR, $dir1) or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    # We only want files
    next unless (-f "$dir1/$file");

    # Use a regular expression to find files with .txt
    next unless ($file =~ m/\.txt/);

    my @partialName = (split /\./, $file);

    #The $matchingFile is the file which contains attributes listed vertically, along side their respective data

    my $matchingFile = "$dir2/input1\.txt ";

    system("awk -F\"\t\" 'FILENAME==\"$dir1/$file\"{a[\$1]=\$1} FILENAME==\"$matchingFile\"{if(a[\$1]){print \$0}}' $dir1/$file $matchingFile > $dir1/$partialName[0]'\_matched.out' ");

}

closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

This is the line works on the command line, but it refuses to work in my perl script.

```
awk -F"\t" 'FILENAME=="input2.txt"{a[$1]=$1} FILENAME=="../../../DataFiles/input1.txt"{if(a[$1]){print $0}}' input2.txt ../../../DataFiles/input1.txt > input2_matched.out
```

By the way, the sheer number of input2 files makes hard coding the above awk line on the command propt a real pain in the butt, which is why I have utilized a perl script which can perform my desired function on every input2 file in the directory, AND keep the naming convention for the output files. I've written similar programs so I know the syntax of

```
system("awk ...blah blah... ");
```

can and does work properly.

I've been stuck on this problem for days now, so any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you to to use hash to solve this kind of problem. that will be must faster.

Comment: What do you mean by hash?

Comment: A good document of hash you will find in this link. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_hashes.htm

Comment: If you still want to process your data in your way . First try to take your command in a variable (example my $cmd = "awk ......"). then print it.then try to run that command on the command line to check its working or not.

Comment: I think you should drop the awk altogether. This is trivial to write in Perl, and will be much simpler to maintain. It's a bad idea to switch to a different language just because you don't know how to implement something in the first language.

Comment: If you really, really want to mix AWK into your Perl, there's always [this](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Inline-Awk-0.04/Awk.pm).

Answer (score 0):

> While there are several different variations on input2, there is only
>   a single input1. I have a perl script with an embedded awk command
>   which is supposed to match names from input2 to input1 and print an
>   output file which contains the names from input2 and the respective
>   values from input1.

I would suggest `find` + `a comparison function` to achieve your objective

```
matcher(){
awk 'NR==FNR{input1record[$1]=$0;next}
    $1 in input1record{print input1record[$1]}' /path/to/input1 "$@" >> /path/to/result
}
export -f matcher
find /path/to/input2_files -type f -name "input2" \
     -exec bash -c 'matcher "$@"' _ {} +
```

**References**

1. The `{} +` with find builds the command line and execute the subshell command , our function in this case, once for all. See [[ find ]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) manpage.
2. Note the I have used `>>` to append the output of subsequent runs to the output file. If this is not desired use `>`.
3. The pattern with `-name` should be adjusted to match all the `input2` filenames

Comment: This approach though short won't be anywhere near `perl` when it comes to speed.